# Installing getnonfreefonts in Linux Mint 21

Tags: installing-fonts

I am unable to install nonfreefonts (revision 2017-06-02) in Linux Mint 21 (Vanessa) and TexLive 2022.

```
wget http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
sudo getnonfreefonts --sys -a && sudo mktexlsr
```

> Resolving mirror.aut.ac.nz (mirror.aut.ac.nz)... 156.62.1.213
> Connecting to mirror.aut.ac.nz (mirror.aut.ac.nz)|156.62.1.213|:443...
> connected. ERROR: cannot verify mirror.aut.ac.nz's certificate, issued
> by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server
> CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:   Unable to locally
> verify the issuer's authority. To connect to mirror.aut.ac.nz
> insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
> [download failed]
>
> Download failed.  Please try again.

I edited the `getnonfreefonts.pl` as root in `/usr/local/bin` and changed line 496 from:

`system ("$WGET", "$getfont_url") == 0`

to

`system ("$WGET", "$getfont_url","--no-check-certificate") == 0`

Re-running the script returns the same error messages.

Is there a workaround/solution to this?

Comment: Does it also not work when you download the installer script directly from the webpage (https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) from the browser?

Comment: It makes no difference if I download the getnonfreefonts.pl script via browser, wget or curl. They all download the script just fine (I prefer working from the command line). The script installs fine into /usr/local/bin. Running the script to download the fonts is not fine returning the message: "Resolving mirror.aut.ac.nz (mirror.aut.ac.nz)... 156.62.1.213 Connecting to mirror.aut.ac.nz (mirror.aut.ac.nz)|156.62.1.213|:443... connected. ERROR: cannot verify mirror.aut.ac.nz's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’: Unable to

Comment: I see, I mistakingly thought that the first `wget` command that you mentioned was the one that failed because tug.org served the file from a mirror - I realize now that both assumptions were incorrect.